# select in bootstrap v4 dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I put a select in a dropdown in bootstrap v4.  It works fine on desktop; however, on mobile the select options won't show.  Everything I try seems to leave desktop working and mobile not.  Help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <span class="dropdown-item" ><input type="text"/></span>
    <span class="dropdown-item" >
      <!--<span>Grid Size</span>-->
      <select class="c-select" style="width: 50%" id="gridSize">
        <option>Grid Size</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get selected value

```
$('#gridSize').val();
```

to get selected text

```
$('#gridSize:selected').text();
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you made a mistake, to get selected text:
$('#gridSize > option:selected').text();
And i dont see why this is an answer to this question...