# select2 in bootstrap v4 dropdown menu

Tags: jquery-select2, twitter-bootstrap-4

This is essentially my question [select in bootstrap v4 dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856314/select-in-bootstrap-v4-dropdown/36857526?noredirect=1#comment61301193_36857526); however, I needed to add a select2 tag to it.  To restate, I want to put a select box in a dropdown menu.  It works on desktop and somewhat (but not really) on mobile.  It is posted at outtopastureenterprises.com/selectInDropdown.html

BTW, without select2, it doesn't work at all on mobile which is why I reposted with this tag.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <span class="dropdown-item" ><input type="text"/></span>
    <span class="dropdown-item" >
      <!--<span>Grid Size</span>-->
      <select class="c-select" style="width: 50%" id="gridSize">
        <option>Grid Size</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').select2();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

All that is needed is `e.preventDefault();` on the parent of the select2.  The location of the dropdown isn't perfect, but it definitely works.